# Procedure to change the color of multiple panels with different names in Delphi

Tags: delphi, procedure

I have a TForm with 5 TPanel controls on it. I need them to change color when they are clicked on.

I can easily write code for each TPanel to change colors, but that consists of too much code, so I was wondering if I could write a procedure to change the color of each one independently and just call this function with the name of each TPanel as a parameter? If not, then is there any other way to do this?

[image: My form containing 5 panels]

Answer (score 7):

This is really easy.

1. Create a new VCL application.
2. Add five `TPanel` controls to the main form.
3. Select all five panels.
4. In the **Object Inspector**, set `ParentBackground` to `False`.
5. In the **Object Inspector**, click the **Events** tab and click the empty field to the right of the `OnClick` row caption. Type `PanelClick` and press Enter.
6. Write the following code:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.PanelClick(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     if Sender is TPanel then
       TPanel(Sender).Color := RGB(Random(255), Random(255), Random(255));
   end;
   ```

[image: Screen recording of five panels. Each panel changes its colour when clicked.]

I think this is what you asked. However, given your image, I suspect you rather would like a toggling behaviour:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.PanelClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
    if Controls[i] is TPanel then
      if Controls[i] = Sender then
        TPanel(Controls[i]).Color := clHighlight
      else
        TPanel(Controls[i]).Color := clBtnFace;
end;
```

This iterates over the child controls of `Self`, since `ControlCount` and `Controls` mean `Self.ControlCount` and `Self.Controls`, respectively. If your target panels have a different parent (a panel, say), iterate over its children instead.

Optionally, you can give the target panels a specific `Tag` value (like `500`) and only change the colour of such panels.

[image: Screen recording of five panels. The last-clicked panel is highlighted.]

And please set `BevelOuter` to `bvNone`. We  have left the 90s.

Comment: Great animated GIFs, but not transparent - your desktop background is too distracting to me. 